# Axis 1.4 pass custom SecureSocketFactory

Tags: java, ssl, axis, keystore, sslsocketfactory

I have an application where for some environment related reasons I need to pass my own securesocketfactory. I went through [Axis 1.4 documentation](https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/integration-guide.html#Example_2)  . Based on this I tried setting my value in multiple ways. All listed below.

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.axis.components.net.SocketFactory", CustomSocketFactory.class.toString());
System.setProperty("org.apache.axis.components.net.SecureSocketFactory",CustomSocketFactory.class.toString());
System.setProperty("axis.socketFactory",CustomSocketFactory.class.toString());
System.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory",CustomSocketFactory.class.toString());
AxisProperties.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory", CustomSocketFactory.class.toString());
AxisProperties.setProperty("axis.socketFactory", CustomSocketFactory.class.toString());
AxisProperties.setProperty("org.apache.axis.components.net.SecureSocketFactory", CustomSocketFactory.class.toString());
AxisProperties.setProperty("org.apache.axis.components.net.SocketFactory", CustomSocketFactory.class.toString());
```

I am doing this just before my `Locator` class is instantiated. But in none of the case when the axis connectivity happened it used my socket factory.

Is there a way to pass my custom SocketFactory? Even if I can pass my custom KeytoreManager it would do the job.

Am at my wits end! The options I have tried like socketFactory might show that. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my mistake. I had to simply pass

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.axis.components.net.SocketFactory", "com.package.myclass");
System.setProperty("org.apache.axis.components.net.SecureSocketFactory","com.package.myclass");
```

I was passing the wrong value.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, so you know if there is a way to apply this properties without touching the global settings? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you have your `ServiceClient` instance, you can get the options and set a property for the protocol handler to use:

```
serviceClient.getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CUSTOM_PROTOCOL_HANDLER, sslProtocol);
```

One of the things a bit tricky about this is that you cannot just use a `SSLSocketFactory`, you have to provide an `org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ProtocolSocketFactory`, which defines a few more methods.

You also have the option of creating your own HTTPClient instance and populating that:

```
serviceClient.getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT, Boolean.TRUE);
serviceClient.getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, httpClient);
```

Comment: There's no such property HTTPConstants.CUSTOM_PROTOCOL_HANDLER in axis 1.4.0.